# Dog hiding under bed until about 2am every night

Tags: dogs, training, sleep

Leading on from my previous post where I had a puppy who is not keen on sleeping in her crate [15 month old moodle crate regression](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31674/15-month-old-moodle-crate-regression)

I gave up. The crate is no more. She has free reign of the house and sleeps wherever she wants.

Bizarrely our nightly routine seems to be this:

1. I go to bed about 11PM
2. She refuses to come into bed with me, but instead sleeps in the lounge room for about an hour.
3. When she comes into my room she will crawl under my bed and fall asleep there.
4. About 2am she either comes into bed OR I have to pull her out from under the bed because she's whining and digging.

She refuses to sleep in the bed until 2am, if I put her under my sheets she just 'nopes' out of there, but once she's settled she falls asleep under the covers and I can't even get her out of the bed until about 11am. She'll gladly sleep on the bed during the day too.

What's going on? I'm guessing she's developed a phobia of the room from the crate, and that is associated with bed time?

When she stays at my partners house she gladly sleeps in the bed, and when I'm not home she'll gladly sleep in my parents bed no problems. It's just my bed.